# Uploading HTML directories to Google Docs?

Tags: html, google-docs

Is it possible to setup a collaborative, editable site on google docs? I have basic data that I've rendered as HTML and have structured into folders where some of the documents link to others. I would like to be able to have these files collaboratively edited and saved (the actual data on the displayed page that are set up as contenteditable HTML tables, not the HTML code).

However when uploading this HTML directory to Google Docs you can edit the individual HTML pages directly and have your changes persist, however the relative links don't work anymore. Is there a way on Google Docs to set this up? If not, alternative ideas are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean by Google Docs API ?

Comment: I think he's wanting Google Sites.